# jquery form submission button not working on mobile / touchscreens

Tags: javascript, jquery

Form submit button not working on mobile / touchscreen devices, it works on laptops but on mobile devices nothing happens, code below:

```
  $('[data-behavior="publish-button"]').on('click', function() {
    $('.editor-form').submit();
  });

  $('.publish-dropdown').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  });
},
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do you get an exception? Is it simply that nothing happens? Please provide more detail to your question.

Comment: nothing happens, sorry for ambiguity, updated question

Comment: Please modify your question to include a **Complete and Verifiable Example**. Without your associated HTML markup, your example is neither complete nor verifiable. Per the rules, a question that asks "Why isn't this working?" and doesn't reproduce the problem is *off-topic*.

Comment: You shouldn't be using jQuery with React. Use built-in JSX event handler `onSubmit` for the form and set submit button `type="submit"`. `e.preventDefault()` to prevent page refresh.

Comment: Chances are that you have a z-index problem on mobile.  Would need you to provide a link to a working example in order to debug.

Comment: You could simply paste your source into a Fiddle and then provide the link.

https://fiddle.jshell.net/

Comment: Figured out a solution. Added button for mobile below form rather than button in nav which works...

Comment: @S.Digital did the button in the nav have `cursor: pointer;`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:-

```
$('[data-behavior="publish-button"]').on('click touchstart', function() {
  $('.editor-form').submit();
});

$('.publish-dropdown').on('click touchstart', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Can you screen share, so that I can debug this myself through team viewer?

Answer (score 0):

If the element you are trying to touch does not have a pointer as the cursor (which is what I assume), it will not be touchable on iOS Safari.

Set `cursor: pointer;` and it will work as expected.